# Office365 API access for all network users' calendars using c#

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365api

So my main objective is to update network user's outlook calendar from sql server data using office365 api every few minutes. I am stuck at how to get access for other user's outlook calendar? Looked at below link but didnt asnwser much...do i need azure subscription in order to do this? If someone can point me to right direction, that would be great

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck at how to get access for other user's outlook calendar?

In this case, you can consider using the application permission.

In Azure AD:

1. register a Web Application in your Azure AD.
2. add “Read and write calendars in all mail boxes” permission 
   [image]
3. generate the application secret key

In your application, call Office 365 Graph API - create events by using application token.

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events

```
        var tmgr = new ApplicationTokenManagement();

        var token = tmgr.AcquireToken(Settings.ResourceUrlOfGraph);

        var api = new Graph.GraphCalendarAPI(token);

        JObject body = new JObject
        {
            {"subject", "Create from Office 365 API"},
            {"start", new JObject { { "DateTime", "2016-03-09T00:00:00"}, { "TimeZone", "China Standard Time" } } },
            {"end", new JObject { { "DateTime", "2016-03-10T00:00:00"}, { "TimeZone", "China Standard Time" } } },
            {"isAllDay", true }
        };

        var task = api.CreateEventAsync(body, "user@youcompany.com");

        task.Wait();
```

You can find the complete sample [here](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/blob/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/Console-with-O365/CreateFullDayEventForUser.cs).

Comment: Doesnt it requires every user to login? I am planning to use this in windows service application where i can access all user's calendar without them logging in. I'm going to use administrator account to access all...is there a way to do this?

Comment: btw i dont see an option to read and write calendars in all mailboxes